# Spotify iOS sdk connect to spotify app remote with existing access token

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, spotify

I'm making an app with flutter and I want to play a song with spotify given a uri. I have already implemented authentication with the spotify web api in my dart code, so I already have a valid access token. I need to use the iOS sdk to play a track with a uri so I need to implement that in swift. What I want to do is pass the access token to the swift code and connect the spotify app remote object with the access token and skip the authentication step that's under the "Set Up User Authorization" section on the [spotify iOS sdk quick start guide](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/ios/quick-start/). Here's my full AppDelegate.swift code

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate, SPTAppRemoteDelegate, SPTAppRemotePlayerStateDelegate  {
    
    let SpotifyClientID = client id
    let SpotifyRedirectURL = redirect uri
    
    lazy var configuration = SPTConfiguration(
      clientID: SpotifyClientID,
      redirectURL: SpotifyRedirectURL
    )
 
    
    private let spotifyMethodChannelName = "spotify"
    private var spotifyAppRemote: SPTAppRemote? = nil
    private var result: FlutterResult? = nil
    
    func appRemoteDidEstablishConnection(_ appRemote: SPTAppRemote) {
      print("connected")
        self.result!("success")
    }
    
    func appRemote(_ appRemote: SPTAppRemote, didDisconnectWithError error: Error?) {
      print("disconnected")
    }
    
    func appRemote(_ appRemote: SPTAppRemote, didFailConnectionAttemptWithError error: Error?) {
        print("failed " + error.debugDescription)
    }
    
    func playerStateDidChange(_ playerState: SPTAppRemotePlayerState) {
      print("player state changed")
    }
    
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
//    FirebaseApp.configure()
    
    let controller : FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
    let spotifyChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: spotifyMethodChannelName,
                                              binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
    spotifyChannel.setMethodCallHandler({
      (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) -> Void in
      // Note: this method is invoked on the UI thread.
        self.result = result
        switch(call.method){
        case "connect":
            let args: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = (call.arguments as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)!
            self.connect(accessToken: args["accessToken"] as! String)
        case "playTrack":
            let args: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = (call.arguments as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)!
            self.playTrack(uri: args["uri"] as! String)
        default:
            result(FlutterError(code: "METHOD CALL DOESN'T EXIST",
            message: "Method call doesn't exist",
            details: nil))
        }
    })
    
    
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
    
    private func connect(accessToken: String) -> Void{
        print(accessToken)
        spotifyAppRemote = SPTAppRemote(configuration: self.configuration, logLevel: .debug)
        spotifyAppRemote!.connectionParameters.accessToken = accessToken
        spotifyAppRemote!.delegate = self
        spotifyAppRemote!.connect()
        
    }
    
    
    private func playTrack(uri: String) -> Void{
        self.spotifyAppRemote?.playerAPI?.play(uri, asRadio: false, callback: {peram1,peram2 in})
        self.result!("success")
    }
}
```

although the relevant part is this connect function

```
    private func connect(accessToken: String) -> Void{
        print(accessToken)
        spotifyAppRemote = SPTAppRemote(configuration: self.configuration, logLevel: .debug)
        spotifyAppRemote!.connectionParameters.accessToken = accessToken
        spotifyAppRemote!.delegate = self
        spotifyAppRemote!.connect()
        
    }
```

This code will successfully connect to the spotify app if the spotify app is currently playing music in the background but will fail to connect otherwise (even if spotify is open in the background but not playing music). The quickstart guide uses a method called authorizeAndPlayUri to play a track but I don't want to authorize since I already have a valid access token. How do I connect to the spotify app even if it isn't open in the background with an access token? Also this is the first time I've ever used iOS native code so it's definitely possible that I've made a swift related mistake that I'm not seeing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try including a prop
{
playURI: "",
}
inside your config

source: https://github.com/cjam/react-native-spotify-remote/issues/75

Answer (score 0):

Well, based on official Spotify sdk documentation, we are out of luck. You need to use authorizeAndPlayURI to wake up Spotify app if it’s not currently running.

https://spotify.github.io/ios-sdk/html/Classes/SPTAppRemote.html#//api/name/connect

Edited:
You may use checkIfSpotifyAppIsActive to check if Spotify app is currently active in the background, to decide to simply connect it or use authorizeAnPlayURI to wake up the app.

https://spotify.github.io/ios-sdk/html/Classes/SPTAppRemote.html#//api/name/checkIfSpotifyAppIsActive:

The good thing about acquiring the access token beforehand is that, if Spotify app happens to be running, there will not be any app switching and things will be smoother. Otherwise, an app switch and continue.